# Importing from MATLAB: transform numpy array of arrays into a matrix?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

So I'm building a classifier. I have received image features in a MATLAB .mat file. When importing this in Python I find that `arr.shape` returns (43000,) and `arr[1].shape` returns (8421,). All elements in arr are numpy arrays of this same shape.

I would like to turn this array of arrays into a matrix of shape (43000, 8421). In other words, stack all the arrays on top of each other. I've tried numpy's `vstack`, `concatenate` and some others, but without any luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've asked other people already, but they were not able to reproduce the problem without numpy automatically creating a matrix already... So I hope that someone on here knows anything on how to deal with these .mat file constructions.

**EDIT: What I've tried so far**

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import sys

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('D:\Thesis backups\Amsterdam/features.mat')
```

Vertical stacking and also concatenating, which both resulted in shape (43000,) aswell:

```
np.vstack(mat['descrs'][0])
```

and

```
np.concatenate(mat['descrs'][0])
```

I've tried so many things that I don't really remember... Sorry. I removed all unsuccessful code. One thing I tried was to create an numpy array of zero's in the same shape. And loop over everything to fill it with the same values. But I didn't get that working either.

Comment: Please add some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: if all images are the same size (i.e 8421) then you should be able to use vertcat (vertical concatenate), if not, please can you specify what your matlab input (from Python) looks like (i.e. is it a cell array or individual vectors) etc

Comment: As fuesika said, please post what you have done so far, and how, specifically, it differs from what you want.   "I've tried..." doesn't tell us how you tried it, and "without any luck" doesn't tell us what went wrong.  Also please post `arr.dtype` and `arr[0].dtype`.

Comment: How are you importing it? With `loadmat`?

Comment: What is `descrs` in MATLAB?  matrix, cell, structure?  size?  What is `mat['descrs']`?  An array with shape  `(43000,)`?  It's `dtype`?  It is clear why you are indexing it with `[0]`.

Comment: Again, tell us what you get from `mat.dtype`, `mat['descrs'].dtype`, and `mat['descrs'][0].dtype`.  Without knowing how your data is structured we can't tell you what to do with it.